# How to set option date as Yesterday Today and Tomarrow?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date

i am trying to set option as date yesterday, today , tomorrow, i am trying to implement below code its working but its not showing yesterday date, i want today's date to be selected as well as it should shows yesterday date and tomorrow date.. how to implement this? any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

```
<select id= "date-range" class="form-control" name="date">
   <option value="yesterday">15th June 2019 (Yesterday) </option>
   <option selected value="today">16th June 2019 (Today) </option>
   <option value="tomorrow">17th June 2019 (Tomorrow) </option>
 </select>
```

jquery

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var dateRange = document.getElementById('date-range'),
monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", 
"Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

for(var day = 0; day < 3; day++) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);
  dateRange.options[dateRange.options.length] = new 
Option([date.getDate(), monthNames[date.getMonth()], 
date.getFullYear()].join(' '), date.toISOString());
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the **day** variable inside the for-loop to add it to today's date. Since it's starting at **0** it won't ever get yesterday's date. Make it start from **-1** instead.

To make an option automatically selected you can use the **defaultSelected** and **selected** parameters of the HTMLOptionElement and set those to true.

Finally to find out what the user has selected you need to attach a **change** event listener to the select element.

```js
var dateRange = document.getElementById('date-range'),
  monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
    "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
  ];
var days = ["yesterday", "today", "tomorrow"];
for (var day = -1; day < 2; day++) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);
    var dateAsString = [date.getDate(), monthNames[date.getMonth()],
    date.getFullYear()
  ].join(' ');
  if (day == 0) {
    dateRange.options[dateRange.options.length] = new
    Option(dateAsString, dateAsString + " (" + days[day + 1] + ")", true, true);
  } else {
    dateRange.options[dateRange.options.length] = new
    Option(dateAsString, dateAsString + " (" + days[day + 1] + ")");
  }
}

function handleSelected(e) {
  console.log(e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].value + " selected");
}

dateRange.addEventListener("change", handleSelected);
```

```html
<select id="date-range" class="form-control" name="date">

</select>
```

Comment: how to use option value and today's date should be selected by default

Comment: @ssbits I refined my answer to include your questions.

Comment: @Dharman I'm not too sure why you're talking about a php based solution here which is clearly completely unnecessary.

Comment: Because of the tags...which I told OP to remove

Comment: Ah okay - I see what you mean. ;)

Comment: @ssbits Sorry I didn't get it - what do you mean?

Comment: You mean you want to get the actual text of the selected option instead of it's index? I've update my answer once more.

Comment: @obscure i want to get option value text "yesterday" and not actual text..

Comment: In this case you need to populate the value property with 'yesterday', 'today' and 'tomorrow'. I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: No problem @ssbits - glad I could help! =)

Comment: @obscure can you add days name too in option.. like --16 jun 2019 (today)- it will be more better then..

Comment: Yes @ssbits - I modified the code a little once more. ;)

Comment: Sorry @ssbits - I made a small mistake. It's fixed!

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can get as below,

    1) Yesterday Date

          let now = new Date();
          var defaultDate = now - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1;
          defaultDate = new Date(defaultDate);

    2)  Today's date
          let now = new Date();
          var defaultDate = now ;
          defaultDate = new Date(defaultDate);

    3) Tomorrow's date

          let now = new Date();
          var defaultDate = now + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1;
          defaultDate = new Date(defaultDate);

    Then you can just format it as per your required one.

    Hope this will help you
```